# Entity Framework 5 and two separate Transactions

Tags: entity-framework

I am busy saving a complex model. So, I create an entity (entityA), and then based on some logic, I may need to create a new entity (entityB) and assign it to a property of entityA.

If I have to do that, I call my very basic logging method:

```
public void LogUserActivity(string description)
{
    var l = new user_log
    {
        description = description,
        error_level_id = 0,
        event_date = DateTime.UtcNow,
        person_id = 0
    };

    Context.user_log.Add(l);
    Context.SaveChanges();

}
```

But the Context.SaveChanges tries to save the main entity creation I am busy doing. So, because I am calling my logging method within a method that is still busy creating the main entity I am saving,. it attempt to save the main entity, and dies.

Can I have my logging 'SaveChanges' only save the changes in my logging method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a separate context for the log entry.